# Jump/Goto next highlighted symbol in lsp-mode

Tags: highlighting, lsp-mode, motion, lsp-ui

Lsp-mode has a function `lsp-document-highlight` bound by default to `s-l a h` which picks the symbol at point and highlights all (semantic) occurrences.

Is there a `goto-next-highlight`. I checked the source of lsp-mode.el and lsp-ui-*.el but did not find candidates so far, probably grepping for the wrong strings.

EDIT: While the answer of @Hi-Angel is great, it can only fully work if this [feature request for lsp-mode](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/2847) is implemented.

Comment: For reference (not a `lsp-mode` solution): it sounds like Emacs built-in function `isearch-forward-thing-at-point` can be used for the described behavior. It's bound to `M-s M-.` by default.

Comment: The whole point of using the language server's support is to not use a *text* search, but to jump around the uses of the semantically same symbol. I use isearch a lot, but it is a different use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of such, but if you want to navigate highlights within a file, here's an interactive function `(lsp-next-document-highlight-in-file)` that implements that.

```lisp
(defun lsp-is-lsp-highlighted (pos)
  (seq-find (lambda (elem) (overlay-get elem 'lsp-highlight))
            (overlays-at pos)))

(defun lsp-lsp-highlight-past-end (pos)
  (overlay-end (seq-find (lambda (elem) (overlay-get elem 'lsp-highlight))
                         (overlays-at pos))))

(defun lsp-next-document-highlight-in-file (&optional recurse)
  "Finds next text highlighted with `lsp-document-highlight'.

Wraps around when no highlight found till the end of the buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((orig (point))
         (prev-pos -1)
         (pos (if (lsp-is-lsp-highlighted orig)
                  ;; skip current highlight if it's at point
                  (lsp-lsp-highlight-past-end orig)
                orig))
         (found nil))
    (while (and (/= prev-pos pos)
                (not (setq found (lsp-is-lsp-highlighted pos))))
      (setq prev-pos pos
            pos (next-overlay-change pos)))
    (if (and (not recurse)
             (not found)
             (goto-char (point-min))
             (not (lsp-next-document-highlight-in-file t)))
        (unless recurse
          (message "No next highlight found")
          (goto-char orig))
      (when found
        (goto-char pos)))))
```

**NOTE:** as @Harald found *(see the comments)*, as of writing the words `lsp-document-highlight` has a drawback that it only highlights symbols that are on the screen. It can be worked around by applying the following change to `lsp-mode.el`:

```
--- a/lsp-mode.el
+++ b/lsp-mode.el
@@ -6119,8 +6119,8 @@ A reference is highlighted only if it is visible in a window."
   (lsp--remove-overlays 'lsp-highlight)
 
   (let* ((wins-visible-pos (-map (lambda (win)
-                                   (cons (1- (line-number-at-pos (window-start win) t))
-                                         (1+ (line-number-at-pos (window-end win) t))))
+                                   (cons (point-min)
+                                         (point-max)))
                                  (get-buffer-window-list nil nil 'visible))))
     (setq lsp--have-document-highlights t)
     (-map
```

You can save the modified function to your init file in a section that gets run after `lsp-mode` is fully initialized. Also, if you're annoyed by this, please report a bug or create a PR to fix that.

Comment: Just right! Great. I started toying with emacs-lisp, but this would have taken me a whole day as I never really programmed with it.

Comment: Sadly it turned out that the overlay is the wrong thing to follow. It is only valid on the visual part of a buffer, i.e. what we see on the screen. The instances of the symbol "below the bottom of the window" are not found :-/

Comment: @Harald actually, now that I'm testing it, I think it's not a problem with the code but an actual bug in either the `lsp-mode` or the lsp-server, because the highlight does not appear even after I scroll buffer. So, here's what I'm testing: I created a `test.sh` with a bunch of `#` lines that end with a `foo="hello"` line and then a `echo ${foo}`. Enabled `lsp`. And then if I execute `lsp-document-highlight` over the first `foo`, the `foo` on the second line gets only highlighted when it's on the screen. But if it's not, then it does not get highlighted. Pls test if you see the same.

Comment: Yes that's what I actually meant, the highlighting is limited to the visible part of the buffer only, sorry for the confusion. But I interpreted this as a feature of the overlay functionality. I started coding the same idea when you already presented your answer, and it looked so nice, but we may be trying to use the overlays for something for which they are not intended.

Comment: @Harald nah, that has nothing to do with overlays not working when out of screen. You can check it yourself: highlight a symbol with `lsp-document-highlight` and then scroll so that no highlighted symbols are on the screen. And use `M-:` to evaluate `(seq-find (lambda (elem) (overlay-get elem 'lsp-highlight)) (overlays-in (point-min) (point-max)))`. If what you're saying it true it will return `nil` as it won't find the overlay in the entire buffer. But for me at least it returns an overlay, so it finds it despite that the overlay is out of sight. Please report a bug to `lsp-mode`.

Comment: Right, yes, not a "feature" of overlays. But I think I found the reason and it seems to be intended. See lsp-mode.el function `lsp--document-highlight-callback` where the doc says: "A reference is highlighted only if it is visible in a window." :-/

Comment: @Harald oh, I see. Well, this limitation seems to be very arbitrary, and for me at least, copying the function and replacing the two calls after the `(cons …` *(there's only one)* to `(point-min)` and `(point-max)` makes it work. Again, I think you can bring it up with `lsp-mode` maintainers; in the meantime for your personal use at least you can just put the modified copy of the function to your init file, right after `lsp-mode` got fully initialized *(so if you're using `use-package`, I think it should be the `:config` section)*. **UPD**: and if you do report it, pls leave a link here.